# Htaccess Passing the whole URL?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

How to PASS the whole incoming any possible URLs to another site AS A VARIABLE?

For example:
'www.old.com' --> 'www.new.com?url=www.old.com'

'www.old.com/subdir/sub/welcome.html' --> 'www.new.com?url=www.old.com/subdir/sub/welcome.html'

'subdomain.old.com/sss.php' --> 'www.new.com?url=subdomain.old.com/sss.php'

Is it even possible?

Comment: I don't even know how to get the whole URL as a variable

Comment: Have you read the documentation for mod_rewrite?

Comment: Yes very very well i know everything. Will you even tell to my dad, teacher? But teacher doesn't seems to know this also, but just asking around!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^(www\.)?old\.com  [NC]
RewriteRule .*   http://new.com?url=%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}  [L]
```

Maps silently any request to

`http://old.com/Anything` or `http://www.old.com/Anything`

To:

`http://new.com?url=RequestedURL` where `RequestedURL` is the whole requested URL.

Example:

`http://www.old.com/subdir/sub/welcome.html?this=is&a=query`

Will be redirected silently to:

`http://www.new.com?url=www.old.com/subdir/sub/welcome.html?this=is&a=query`

According to the question, there is no condition or pattern to trigger the redirection: All requests to `old.com` will be redirected.

For a permanent and visible redirection, replace [L] with [R=301,L]